# ROS Real Time Publisher

Tags: ros, ros-control, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to ROS and am trying to understand how I can use the real time publishers. I followed this link http://wiki.ros.org/realtime_tools

For using this, would I require a RT kernel or the usual Ubuntu kernel would be sufficient?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290353/ros-real-time-publisher/) by [Deba](https://answers.ros.org/users/34715/deba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In short:

> would I require a RT kernel

Yes. A real-time kernel would be required.

For some longer discussions about ROS (1) and real-time, see #q206052.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Deba](https://answers.ros.org/users/34715/deba/) on 2018-05-03**:
Thanks very much, that link helped a lot. :)